# Git windows installer not letting me choose install location

Tags: windows, git

I am trying to install git using their windows installer from https://git-scm.com/downloads  (I have windows 10). When I try to install Git I get `unable to get system config` then I get `" C:\Users\Me\Appdata\Local\Temp\is-VML96.tmp\git-config-get.txt"`

Its weird but If I click `okay` through both it takes me to the standard install setup as seen below:

[image]

Now if I click `next` it SHOULD take me to this screen:

[image]

The problem is I never get this screen to choose where I want to install git. I never get this screen above, my computer tries to install it to my system reserved which is only 100Mb.

I have tried multiple different versions of git.

What is causing git not to allow me to choose an install location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the installation executable from a command line and pass `/help` you'll get a list of additional commands you can run. The one you need is:

```
/DIR="x:\dirname"
```

Here's the list of available arguments:

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much I never would have thought about doing it this way. For other people with this problem: open cmd > cd to your downloads folder > run `Git-2.31.1-64-bit.exe /DIR="C:\Program Files"`  Make sure the version you are trying to install matches the one in your downloads folder.