# Git installation windows "unable to get system config"

Tags: windows, git, installation, windows-10

I have a question potentially similar to this: [Git windows installer not letting me choose install location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272330/git-windows-installer-not-letting-me-choose-install-location) But the suggestion does not work for me and I believe to have a different underlying problem.

I am trying to install git using their windows installer from https://git-scm.com/downloads (I have windows 10). When I try to install Git I get

> "unable to get system config"

then I get

> "C:\Users\Me_but_written_wrong\Appdata\Local\Temp\is-VML96.tmp\git-config-get.txt"

And then each error message exactly the same once more.
My Username in the error message path starts correctly, but ends with "~1" instead of the last two letters of my name.

Also this is the first time installing Git on this laptop, but I do have git installed on a different machine with in the same company network, so there might be some data stored in unexpected places. As already mentioned I tried installing git from the command line with a given path in a local drive, but did not have any success. The given folder path also stayed the same.
Furthermore I made sure the system variable path does not contain any git related paths, as it is something I read in other places.

Edit: My problem might be system variable related. Within the system variables path is defined using %USERPROFILE%, when I use cmd or the file explorer I my name shows up correctly. But git must get the path from somewhere.

```
C:\Users\Me_correctly>set | find "~"
TEMP=C:\Users\Me_with~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\Me_with~1\AppData\Local\Temp
```

When looking at system variables however, TEMP and TMP are also declared using the %USERPROFILE%.

Comment: If you try to install from the command line, you can pick any location. Are you still getting the ~ issue from the command line if you use an absolute path (no variables)?

Comment: Regarding the ~1 problem, I would take a look at your local variables to see which ones are using ~. I'm not sure but perhaps Git for Windows looks at %USERPROFILE% by default if you don't specify a location. Maybe this would give you some insight from a windows command prompt: `set | find "~"`

Comment: set | find "~" returns a list of the two folders with ~1 in the name. When I navigate to the folders using the explorer however. It shows up written correctly. Also, in the system path variable it is just referenced by %USERPROFILE%

Comment: I get the same error message, when adding the full path as variable when running the install .exe. I do get the feeling now however, that the system variable is the problem.

Comment: I have those same ~1 in the TEMP and TMP on my system. Now I'm wondering if that's just a red herring.

Comment: In the question you linked to, they had the same error, and they were able to click through the errors and continue with the install (but the default location didn't have enough space for them). Are you able to click through and continue?

Comment: Yes I can click though it, but I get an additional error at the end. With my new found knowledge I am pretty

Comment: I am pretty...sure you intended to say more?

Comment: Me too. Started editing instantly, but was needed elsewhere. By now I accually somehow someway got the installation to go through. I still feel like I have many underlying problems. That already started to make things more complicated than they would need to be. (E.g. running git in VS Code) but I will get it done. Thenk you very much for your effords.